# iOS prevent default image focusing

Tags: ios, canvas, mobile-safari

I have a canvas in a webpage and I am trying to test it on my ipad. However, when I did a long  touch on that canvas, a light blue rectangle will appear around that canvas and asking me if to copy that. Is there a way to disable that? I tried:

```
$(document).bind("touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

$(document).bind("touchmove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

It does work, but the whole webpage stop responding to the event listeners I bind to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set CSS for the element(s) to prevent select:

```
canvas
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }
```